# Throw and Catch Errors - Linux

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I have the command `awk -F, 'length($1) != 9 || $2 > 9999{print "ERROR at line "NR;}' file.txt >> log.txt`

I need to know if this this command catches anything and if it does to run an if-then set of commands.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: any ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out another way. I had the command write to an error file, then checked the size of the other file. If it was greater than 0kb, then I know that there's errors.

Works great now.